# Pass Form PHP Variables to JSON Encode

Tags: php, json, encode, sendgrid

I have a form with these values:

```
    $firstName = strip_tags(trim($_POST['first-name']));
    $lastName = strip_tags(trim($_POST['last-name']));
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST['user-email']),FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

I'm trying to pass these values onto this:

```
    $request_body = json_decode('[{
        "first_name" : "Tom",
        "last_name" : "Hanks",
        "email" : "example@gmail.com"
    }]');
```

Tried saving the form values to an array and passing it into *json_decode* where $userArray are the form values, but not go. Example:

```
$request_body = json_decode($userArray, true);
```

All of this is to pass these form values into an API (SendGrid), but it's just not working for me and their documentation is not very descriptive. I guess they want a specific request format. Here's an example of their request body from their Github page. I can have these values hard coded in and it works fine, but the idea is for the form to pass in these user name and email values automatically.

```
$request_body = json_decode('[
  {
    "age": 25, 
    "email": "example@example.com", 
    "first_name": "", 
    "last_name": "User"
  }, 
  {
    "age": 25, 
    "email": "example2@example.com", 
    "first_name": "Example", 
    "last_name": "User"
  }
]');
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: does sendgrid api accept json encoded string?

Comment: Well I tried using json_encode but it didn't work for me either. Is that what you're referring too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you sent your post :

```
$array[0]['email'] = filter_var(trim($_POST['user-email']),FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$array[0]['first_name'] = strip_tags(trim($_POST['first-name']));
$array[0]['last_name'] = strip_tags(trim($_POST['last-name']));

echo json_encode($array);
```

Result :

```
[{"email":"john.doe@exemple.com","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe"}]
```

The [0] might have been an issue, it produce the "[" "]" when you read the json_decode output and reproduce the exact same array when decoded with json_decode.

So if their script is looking for integers as keys, if you omit the [0], they will get an array in the following format $array['email'] etc. This might be an issue.

If you would like to reproduce that in a loop and send multiple entries at once

you could write it this way instead :

```
$array[] = array('email' => filter_var(trim($_POST['user-email']),FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL),
                 'first_name' => strip_tags(trim($_POST['first-name'])),
                 'last_name' => strip_tags(trim($_POST['last-name']))
);
```

You will still be missing the "age". Make sure it is not a mandatory field!

Comment: When I echo out their example request that works it looks like this:

array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (3) { ["first_name"]=> string(3) "Tom" ["last_name"]=> string(5) "Hanks" ["email"]=> string(19) "example@example.com" } }

Comment: The way it's done in the snippet I provided, if you would post Tom, Hanks and example@example.com  to your script, it should output the exact same thing as you sent here.

So, can you verify you get everthing in your post request ( var_dump($_POST) ) and then that the data in your array are correct ( var_dump($request_body) ). 

Do you send your request as a POST to "$url/contactdb/recipients" in the "request_body" attribute?

Comment: Actually your solution might work, will test a bit and mark it solved if all is ok. I ended up skipping the json encode part entirely thanks to ScottSmudger clarification.

Comment: This works but no need to use json_encode at all, just pass in the $array and presto.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be getting a little confused while using `json_decode()` and `json_encode()`.

`json_encode()` encodes a PHP array into a JSON array.
Whereas `json_decode()` decodes a JSON array back into a PHP array.

In regards to your situation the following should produce the same output:

```
$array = array(
    "first_name" => "Tom",
    "last_name" => "Hanks",
    "email" => "example@gmail.com"
);

echo json_encode($array);
```

Produces:

`{"first_name":"Tom","last_name":"Hanks","email":"example@gmail.com"}`

Using these functions to build the array then encode/decode to/from JSON is far better than manually creating the JSON array. As this avoids any syntax errors that you may create.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this is what I have but it returns an error {"errors":[{"message":"request body is invalid"}]}

Comment: Is it possible that the `$_POST` variables don't have values?